# "Forever unfulfillable, yet him fulfilling who hears it, utterly"

Tags: meaning, amadeus, peter-shaffer

This is from the play *Amadeus* by Peter Shaffer:

> "What?! What is this? Tell me, Signore! What is this pain? What is this need in the sound? **Forever unfulfillable, yet him fulfilling who hears it, utterly.** Is this Your need? Can it be Yours?” […] I was suddenly frightened. It seemed to me that I had heard a voice of God – and that it issued from a creature whose own voice I had also heard – and it was the voice of an obscene child!"

What is the meaning of the part "Forever unfulfillable, yet him fulfilling who hears it, utterly"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure where you got “him fulfilling” from: the [printed text of the play](https://archive.org/details/petershaffersama0000shaf/page/18/mode/2up) has “fulfilling him”.

In this speech Salieri [personifies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personification) the music (the Adagio from Mozart’s [Serenade No. 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenade_No._10_(Mozart))) as expressing a “need” which is “unfulfillable”, that is, a desire which cannot be satisfied. The music “fulfills him who hears it, utterly”, that is, it is completely gratifying for Salieri to listen to:

> *Salieri:* [… The oboe] hung there unwavering, piercing me through, till breath could hold it no longer, and a clarinet withdrew it out of me, and sweetened it into a phrase of such delight it had me trembling.
>
> <sub>Peter Shaffer (1981). [*Amadeus*, p. 18](https://archive.org/details/petershaffersama0000shaf/page/18/mode/2up). New York: Harper & Row.</sub>

Why Salieri says that the Adagio expresses an unfulfillable need is not clear at first. The movement has a lyrical oboe solo, to be sure, but resolves itself fairly conventionally with a perfect cadence and an E♭ chord (Mozart’s favourite key, symbolic of the Trinity as it has three flats). But in the next scene we get:

> *Salieri:* I ran home and buried my fear in work. More pupils—till there were thrity and forty. More committees to help musicians. More motets and anthems to God’s glory. And at night I prayed for just one thing. “Let your voice enter *me*! Let *me* conduct you! … *Let* me!”
>
> <sub>[Shaffer, p. 19](https://archive.org/details/petershaffersama0000shaf/page/18/mode/2up).</sub>

So it is really Salieri who has the unfulfillable desire, that is, to write music as beautiful as Mozart’s, and in the earlier speech he is projecting this feeling onto Mozart’s Adagio.